# How can you get the next item in the tab order without actually changing the currently focused item?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, frameworkelement

In our WPF app, we need to know which control would get the focus next if we were to press the Tab key. However we don't want the focus to actually change. We just need to know who would get the focus.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
var predictionElement = elementWithFocus.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Up);
Control controlElement = predictionElement as Control;
```

[see here...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.predictfocus?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-frameworkelement-predictfocus(system-windows-input-focusnavigationdirection))

Caution: PredictFocus does not support all constants, e.g. .Next cannot be used.

Comment: Yes, but as you correctly pointed out, this doesn't work for the very case I was trying to check... `next`.  That said, I posted this eight years back and for the life of me can't remember what I was working on that I needed this! haha!  Maybe it was for an old job. :)

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand,
you can achieve this by

1. Looping all the controls on that container/page
2. Check the Tab index property
3. And the control you need will have the Tabindexofcuurrentcontrol +1 
   hope this will help